# I want to merge two cells together in the proposed html layout

Tags: html, css

I'm using [this layout](http://tympanus.net/Freebies/Boxify/) and as you can see there is a section with 8 pictures on the bottom of the page - each of them is a hyperlink to the bigger image. It works pretty neat, esp. when you resize the page to smaller size, then the 4 cells becomes 2 and it looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSaBE.jpg). I want to change it a little, so that two first pictures are merged together, so the layout could look [like this](http://i.imgur.com/hvQotxm.png), and when the user resizes it, it would show him a proper layout [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJRW3.png). So far the html code for that specific part of the page looks like this:

```
<section class="screenshots" id="screenshots">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <ul class="grid">
                        <li>
                            <figure>
                                <img src="img/02-screenshot.jpg" alt="Screenshot 01">
                                <figcaption>
                                <div class="caption-content">
                                    <a href="img/large/02.jpg" class="single_image">
                                        <i class="fa fa-search"></i><br>
                                        <p>User Centric Design</p>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                </figcaption>
                            </figure>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <figure>
                                <img src="img/03-screenshot.jpg" alt="Screenshot 01">
                                <figcaption>
                                <div class="caption-content">
                                    <a href="img/large/03.jpg" class="single_image">
                                        <i class="fa fa-search"></i><br>
                                        <p>Responsive and Adaptive</p>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                </figcaption>
                            </figure>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <figure>
                                <img src="img/04-screenshot.jpg" alt="Screenshot 01">
                                <figcaption>
                                <div class="caption-content">
                                    <a href="img/large/04.jpg" class="single_image">
                                        <i class="fa fa-search"></i><br>
                                        <p>Absolutely Free</p>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                </figcaption>
                            </figure>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <ul class="grid">
                        <li>
                            <figure>
                                <img src="img/06-screenshot.jpg" alt="Screenshot 01">
                                <figcaption>
                                <div class="caption-content">
                                    <a href="img/large/06.jpg" class="single_image">
                                        <i class="fa fa-search"></i><br>
                                        <p>Exclusive to Codrops</p>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                </figcaption>
                            </figure>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <figure>
                                <img src="img/07-screenshot.jpg" alt="Screenshot 01">
                                <figcaption>
                                <div class="caption-content">
                                    <a href="img/large/07.jpg" class="single_image">
                                        <i class="fa fa-search"></i><br>
                                        <p>Made with Love</p>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                </figcaption>
                            </figure>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <figure>
                                <img src="img/08-screenshot.jpg" alt="Screenshot 01">
                                <figcaption>
                                <div class="caption-content">
                                    <a href="img/large/08.jpg" class="single_image">
                                        <i class="fa fa-search"></i><br>
                                        <p>In Sydney, Australia</p>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                </figcaption>
                            </figure>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

and the css code looks like this:

```
/* ==========================================================================
Screenshots Intro
========================================================================== */
.screenshots-intro {
    padding: 170px 0 100px 0;
    background-color: #f6f7f9;
}
.screenshots-intro h1 {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: #24374b;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 22px;
}
.screenshots-intro p {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    color: #778899;
}

/* ==========================================================================
Screenshots
========================================================================== */
.screenshots ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.screenshots ul li {
    float: left;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: #000;
    list-style: none;
}
.screenshots figure {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.screenshots figure img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}
.screenshots figure:hover img, .screenshots figure:focus img {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
.screenshots figcaption {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 25% 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(63, 97, 132, 0.85);
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}
.screenshots figcaption a {
    color: #fff
}
.screenshots figcaption a:hover, .screenshots figcaption a:focus {
    color: #73d0da
}
.screenshots figure:hover figcaption, .screenshots figure:focus figcaption {
    opacity: 1
}
.visible {
    opacity: 1
}
.screenshots figure.cs-hover figcaption {
    opacity: 1
}
.screenshots figcaption i {
    font-size: 35px
}
.screenshots figcaption p {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 400;
}
.screenshots figcaption .caption-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -40px;
    margin-left: -100px;
    width: 200px;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 15px);
    -ms-transform: translate(0px, 15px);
    transform: translate(0px, 15px);
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}
.screenshots figure:hover figcaption .caption-content, .screenshots figure:focus figcaption .caption-content {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    -ms-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
}
```

I know it's a lot of code, but maybe anyone of you have the idea of how to change this particular part of the layout to have it as I included in the pictures? Thanks.

Comment: You should include a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 0):

This is the updated answer.

I am attaching the code and jsfiddle link with it.

Just replace the src of the images with yours to see the results.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
  .container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  img {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  /* this css is just for understanding */
  .a {
    background-color: red;
  }
  .b {
    background-color: green;
  }
  .c {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  .d {
    background-color: black;
  }
  /* this css is just for understanding */
  /* this is the logic to change the positions of image */
  @media (min-width: 320px) {
    .a,
    .b,
    .c,
    .d {
      width: 100%;
      float: left;
    }
  }
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .a,
    .b,
    .c,
    .d {
      width: 50%;
      float: left;
    }
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="a">
      <img src="img/1.png" height="222" width="581">
    </div>
    <div class="b">
      <img src="img/2.jpg" height="222" width="581">
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      <img src="img/3.jpg" height="222" width="581">
    </div>
    <div class="d">
      <img src="img/4.png" height="222" width="581">
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

this is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/avijitkr/5x6gumcx/) link

Comment: could you give me the quick peek of the code for that? I'm not sure if I get your suggestion right..